# AS3: Can't get lines to clear

Tags: actionscript-3, line

So what I have set up is the pattern unlock screen with the dots and you draw your pattern then the screen unlocks. But the issue is the pattern won't be terminated unless you end the mouse cursor directly on a dot. If you go pass the dot nothing will happen but the lines will stay on the screen and you'll still be at the lock screen. Then the used will have to click to clear the lines and try it again. I've been playing around with it but cant seem to figure out why it's working like this.

Here's the code

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;
    import flash.display.Shape;



    public class Main extends Sprite
    {    
        private var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();
        private var dots:Array = []; // Stores the in stage movieclips
        private var pattern:Array = []; //The pattern entered by the user 
        private var pass:Array;

        public function Main():void
        {
            dots = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine]; //add the clips in stage
            pass = [one,four,seven,eight,five,two]; //The correct pattern to proceed
            addChildAt(lineContainer, this.getChildIndex(one)); //the line container right behind the first dot.
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void //adds the listeners to each dot
        {
            var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, initiatePattern);
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern); 

            }
        }

        /* Adds a mouse over listener and uses it to add the number of the dot to the pattern */

        private function initiatePattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            pattern = []; //reset array
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear lines

            for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
            {
                dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
            }

                    addPattern(e); //trigger the mouse over for this element
        }

        private function addPattern(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (pattern.indexOf(e.currentTarget) == -1) { 
                pattern.push(e.currentTarget); //adds the pattern on mouse over
                drawLines();

                var dot:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
                if(dot.currentFrame < 2) dot.play(); //play only if on the first frame
            }
        }

        private function drawLines():void {
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear the current lines
            lineContainer.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00FF00); //thickness (8px) and color (green) of the lines

             if (pattern.length > 1) { //don't draw if there aren't at least two dots in the pattern
             lineContainer.graphics.moveTo(pattern[0].x + pattern[0].width * .0, pattern[0].y + pattern[0].height * .0); //move to first
         for (var i:int = 1; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        lineContainer.graphics.lineTo(pattern[i].x + pattern[i].width * .0, pattern[i].y + pattern[i].height * .0); //draw a line to the current dot
    }
          }

              lineContainer.graphics.endFill();

        }

        private function stopPattern(e:MouseEvent):void //stops storing the pattern on mouse up
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
            {
                dots[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
                dots[i].gotoAndStop(1); //go back to the first frame
            }

            checkPattern();
        }

        private function checkPattern():void //compares the patterns
        {
            var pLength:int = pass.length;
            var correct:int = 0;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < pLength; i++) //compares each number entered in the user array to the pass array
            {
                if (pass[i] == pattern[i])
                {
                    correct++;
                }
            }

            if (correct == pLength) //if the arrays match
            {
              //Hides Sign In
              MovieClip(root).LockScreen.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).RTID.visible = false;
              MovieClip(root).SignIn.visible = false;
              //Turns On Main Menu
              MovieClip(root).gamemenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).biggamesmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).totaltextmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).tmenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).smenu_mc.visible = true;
              MovieClip(root).optionsmenu_mc.visible = true;
            }

            pattern = []; //clears the user array
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear the lines

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mouse over on Android? Are you sure those event actually trigger?

Comment: Yes that's just how AS3 works haven't tested it on a touch screen yet but from what i read and was told it should work properly @BotMaster

Comment: I think you should first confirm that mouse over does produce a result. If it doesn't then the whole question is unsolvable.

Comment: This is way too confusing, the question is tagged Android but haven't tested it in Android? So why is it tagged Android if that platform is out of the picture? In which platform are you trying to make this work?

Comment: @BotMaster `mouseOver` fires at the same time `mouseDown` or `dragOver` does in actionscript on an android device (I just debugged this on my phone). Though the event is ambgious, it is detectable, but doesn't have the same interpretation as it would on a device with a pointer

Comment: I thought as much. Using different events that will fire at the same time might mess up the functionality. You probably should just stick with mouse down or better yet use TouchEvent (let me know if you need some guidelines on this)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add the `MOUSE_UP` listener on the stage instead of each dot.

1. **Remove** this line in the **addListeners** method:

   ```
   dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern);
   ```
2. In the **initiatePattern** method, add this line:

   ```
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern);
   ```
3. In the **stopPattern** method, add this line:

   ```
   stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPattern);
   ```

Now no matter where to cursor is when you release the mouse (as long as the application has focus), it will stop the pattern.

Also (as per some comments), mouse events work just fine on mobile devices as long as you haven't enabled multitouch.

---

HERE is what the modified methods should look like now:

```
    private function addListeners():void //adds the listeners to each dot
    {
        var dotsLength:int = dots.length;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < dotsLength; i++)
        {
            dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, initiatePattern);
        }
    }

    /* Adds a mouse over listener and uses it to add the number of the dot to the pattern */

    private function initiatePattern(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        pattern = []; //reset array
        lineContainer.graphics.clear(); //clear lines

        for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
        {
            dots[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
        }

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopPattern);
        addPattern(e); //trigger the mouse over for this element
    }

    private function stopPattern(e:MouseEvent):void //stops storing the pattern on mouse up
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < dots.length; i++)
        {
            dots[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addPattern);
            dots[i].gotoAndStop(1); //go back to the first frame
        }

        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopPattern);
        checkPattern();
    }
```

---

And just for fun, here is a slightly more efficient way to check for the correct pattern.

```
    private function checkPattern():void //compares the patterns
    {
        var correct:Boolean = true;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < pass.length; i++) //compares each number entered in the user array to the pass array
        {
            if (pattern.length != pass.length || pass[i] != pattern[i]) //this way if they select less than the correct amount of dots, it won't error, and you stop the loop as soon as there's something incorrect
            {
                correct = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (correct) //if the arrays match
        {.....
```

Comment: Thank you for the info very helpful, but the pattern still continues after the dots and it no longer works with this added code. Any idea why?

Comment: It's now clearing properly just it removed the line from drawing and once you do the correct pattern nothing is happening

Comment: I want to say it's because it's not actually "picking" up the dots you are going over anymore hence why the line won't draw and the pattern not be accepted

Comment: None of the code changes in my answer would cause the dots not to work.  Are you sure you didn't remove something not listed in my answer?  Like the `MOUSE_OVER` listener?

Answer (score 1):

Your only checking the pattern on a `MOUSE_UP` event.  You need to check it in `MOUSE_OVER`.  Add a call to `checkPattern()` in `addPatern()`.

```
if (pattern.indexof(e.currentTarget)==-1) {
   patern.push(e.currentTarget);
   drawLines();

   var dot:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
   if(dot.currentFrame < 2) dot.play();

   checkPattern(); // <---
}
```

As the user moves the mouse over the dots, the program calls `addPatern()` which then checks the pattern to see if it is correct. (aka. `if (correct=pLength)`)

EDIT:

You need to put the call to clear the lines and the pattern in the `if` statement where you actually check if the pattern is correct. That's why the lines aren't rendering.

```
if (correct==pLength)
{
  ...

  // Set pattern to [], clear screen, etc.
}
```

Comment: sorry for vote down but the question is tagged Android so I don't think mouse over is an option.

Comment: Adding that checkPattern(); there doesn't allow the line to draw anymore and also the dots still stay light when you go pass them

Comment: @BotMaster I suggested MOUSE_OVER because the OP is setting MOUSE_OVER listeners in initiatePattern().

Comment: removing the vote down, I think the question is malformed and misleading. User says he doesn't test on Android but question is tagged Android.

Comment: checking the pattern every dot mouse over makes easy to randomly guess the pattern.  If Android is the model here, then you only check the pattern on mouse up (when the user is done inputting the pattern)